# Cross tab/ Dynamic Pivoting in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am trying to create a dynamic pivoting in postgresql. 
my query is including 3 dimensions in which one includes a case statement. and one measure. I have tried various solutions found on web but none is working. pls help me with this.

Comment: You should expand your question with sample data and expected output. Probably you can do it using tablefunc extension.

Comment: You could also try using psql `\crosstabview` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Thank for your reply. I have tried \crosstab, tablefunc extension.but it is not satisfying my requirment. Here is my requirment. I have a requiremwnt where category need to be changed dynamically.

my query and the, My expected output is shown here. my category changes over the selected date range. pls find query and expected output at
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ayYBSIirowiutgxg9p5KINQc3U3ISPnp

Comment: Any Solution..?